# Decorating plain HTML with Angular attributes

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular but am well down the line with my first application. It's quite complex so I've included a much simplified example to explain my problem.

I've got an Angular template like this;

```
    <html>
        <head>
        ...
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="MyController">
            <h1>My Template</h1>
            <ol id="menu">
                <li ng-repeat="section in sections" ng-click="goTo($index)">{{section.name}}</li>
            </ol>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <?php echo $html; ?>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The idea is that the ordered list will act like a menu to show the current section and hide all of the others. My PHP script creates the sections from existing HTML that looks like this;

```
    <section>
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
        <p>Text for page 2</p>
    </section>
```

I would like to somehow use Angular itself to perform the following;

1. Add Angular markup to the plain HTML
2. Get the text from inside the first H1 tag of each section and use it to populate scope.sections

I guess the final result would look like this;

```
    <html>
        <head>
        ...
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="MyController">
            <h1>My Template</h1>
            <ol id="menu">
                <li ng-repeat="section in sections" ng-click="goTo($index)">{{section.name}}</li>
            </ol>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <section ng-if="currentSection == 1">
                    <h1>Page 1</h1>
                    <p>Some text here</p>
                </section>
                <section ng-if="currentSection == 2">
                    <h1>Page 2</h1>
                    <p>Text for page 2</p>
                </section> 
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I realise that I could do the first part with some PHP string replacement but I wondered if there was an Angular solution as in the real project, PHP replacement is not feasible.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd change this around a little. Firstly, I'd send all of the sections data to the angularjs app as a JSON array via an AJAX call after the page loads. You could also output the sections data as JSON directly on the page and then load that data into your controller, but this would be less efficient for the initial load time.

I typically do this using an AngularJS Factory to call a specific URL that would simply echo the json_encoded data and exit. More information on factories here http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

Once you've pulled in your sections as JSON, you should have an array and each item in the array should be a section object with basic information- such as name and content. From there, you simply do the ng-repeat twice, like so:

**In The Controller JS**

```
// Init variables
$scope.location = 0; // set default
$scope.sections = []; // Create sections array

// Define function to 'go to' a section
$scope.goTo = function($index){
    $scope.location = $index;
}

jQuery('#wrapper section').each(function(){
    var name = jQuery('h2', this).first().text();
    var content = jQuery('p', this).first().text();
    var section = {name: name, content: content};
    $scope.sections.push(section);
};
```

**In the HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyController">
        <h1>My Template</h1>
        <ol id="menu">
            <li ng-repeat="section in sections" ng-click="goTo($index)">{{section.name}}</li>
        </ol>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <section ng-if="location == $index" ng-repeat="section in sections">
                <h1>{{section.name}}</h1>
                {{section.content}}
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mikel, due to the nature of the project, I have to inject raw markup from html files into the template. Unfortunately I can't specify that the sections are provided as JSON formatted objects ;-(

Comment: Do you have control of the HTML? Whatever is currently looping through the sections and outputting the <section></section> div could just be json_encoded on the page as a JS variable. 

If you absolutely do not have control over any of the HTML I can provide some code (using jQuery) that will parse the html and add it to the AngularJS app, then you're good to go with the rest of my answer from there.

Comment: @Tom Hey Tom, I just updated my answer with some jQuery that populates $scope.sections, but honestly this is the way wrong way of doing it. How did you plan on adding <section ng-if="currentSection == 1"> this ng-if to the HTML if you have no control over it?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mikel, in the end I went for a jqLite solution to get something working in time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more interesting answer to this but for now, here's the solution I came up with;

First, a function to set up my nav - it basically finds all `<section>` tags and for each, grabs the first occurrence of `<h1>`, adding the text to my $scope.sections binding. This results in an array of strings that my ngRepeat can use to build the menu list.

```
    function setupNavigation() {
        angular.forEach(angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('section')), function(value, key) {
            $scope.sections.push(angular.element(value.querySelector('h1')).text());
        });
    }
```

Then a function which is attached to the ngClick of my repeated list items. It hides all sections before showing the relevant one.

```
    $scope.goTo = function(index) {
        angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('section')).hide().eq(index).show();
    }
```

There will be a more robust solution out there using $compile and directives probably but as it's only day 2 of learning Angular I think I'll leave this for another day!